# How to detect NullReferenceException before runtime?

Tags: c#

Need to know is there any free tool available or on to how to detect NullReferenceException before runtime ?

Say, I have piece of code like

```
    SomeObject.SomeMethod() // Here SomeObject can throw NullReferenceException
```

Is there any way to detect this before runtime ?

Comment: NullReferenceException is runtime exception

Comment: It cant detect it before runtime, you can code to check if its null and do something better instead of the exception.. or handle the exception and do something

Comment: Write good unit tests

Comment: You can get a free month with resharper and it will let you know where they are, it will also suggest other fixes of which would be your decision to use or not. I only do it if i understand the change, if not i dont. But it is good. If you dont have the money for a license then it isnt a long term solution

Comment: No budget with me, is there any free tool like resharper available?

Answer (score 5):

Why not check is `SomeObject` is null before calling it?

C#6

```
SomeObject?.SomeMethod();
```

Prior to C#6

```
if(SomeObject!=null) SomeObject.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Depends if you're using C#6

Comment: This would work, but i'm using .Net 4.5 :(

Comment: @user3326623 the framework version isn't relevant to your ability to use C# 6. You could use it with .NET 2.0 if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to catch the error because its a runtime error however you can place the code within a try catch to catch and handle the error however you want

```
try {
    SomeObject.SomeMethod() 
}
catch(NullReferenceException) {    
 //catch exception here
}
```

Comment: If you expect SomeObject to be null, then you should not use exception handling to do the check, it's too computationally expensive.  Even a try/catch that is never called uses thousands of extra cycles, if an exception is thrown, there will be millions of extra cycles.